# sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `'' when running sed as a Kubernetes arg

Tags: kubernetes, sed, apache-pulsar

I'm trying to run an Apache Pulsar container as part of a Kubernetes deployment. I need to change the port of Apache Pulsar. The entry for Pulsar in my Kubernetes yaml looks like this

```
- name: pulsar
  image: apachepulsar/pulsar:3.1.2
  args: ["sed", "-i", "'s/webServicePort=8080/webServicePort=8082/g'", "conf/standalone.conf", ";", "bin/pulsar", "standalone"]
```

I ran play kube and got the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is due to the extra single quotes around the `sed` expression.

Try doing this to fix it:

Replace your `args` line with:

```yaml
args: ["sh", "-c", "sed -i 's/webServicePort=8080/webServicePort=8082/g' conf/standalone.conf && bin/pulsar standalone"]
```

This correction uses `sh -c` to execute a shell command and correctly formats the `sed` command without extra quotes. The `&&` is used to run `bin/pulsar standalone` after the `sed` command successfully executes.